# How to check a SQL Server view dependencies

Tags: sql-server, view

I need to modify a SQL Server view in a large database and need to know what other objects in this database use this view. How can I do that?

I tried viewing dependencies in SQL Server Management Studio but that does not list the objects that depend on this view (I know of at least one stored procedure that depends on this view, and it is not listed as a dependency).

The other option that I considered is scripting the whole database and doing the text search in it, but I want to see if there is an automated way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to query syscomments table and find the usage.

```
select o.name,o.type from sys.syscomments c
inner join sys.objects o
on o. object_id = c.id
where c.text like '%your view name%'
```

Update #1

```
select o.name,o.type from sys.sql_modules m
inner join sys.objects o
on o.object_id = m.object_id
where m.definition like '%your view name%'
```

Comment: Thank you. That did not work. I think your where clause should read "where o.name like '%your view name%'". But even if I try that I just get one row with the name of my view as a result.

Comment: btw to ur earlier comment it was `o.name`, it is `c.text`, since we are searching the text for the view usage

Comment: Perfect, both of the queries returned the list of objects that depend on this view.